# Why is the 430EX more expensive than the 430EX II?

Tags: pricing, hotshoe-flash

I'm about to sell my Canon 430EX and trying to determine a fair price for it. Looking at Amazon, it seems like the 430EX is more expensive than the 430EX II. I'm a bit confused. Any ideas why this might be?

430EX : [http://www.amazon.com/Canon-430EX-Speedlite-Flash-Cameras/dp/B000AO3L84/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AO3L84) (~$430)
430EX II: [http://www.amazon.com/Canon-Speedlite-II-Digital-Cameras/dp/B001CCAISE/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CCAISE) (~$262)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas why this might be?

The 430 EX II is sold *by* Amazon while the 430 EX is sold *through* Amazon *by* Crawford's Superstore.

Answer (score 2):

This often happens with discontinued products — flashes, cameras, snacks, cleaning supplies — on Amazon. All the vendors offering a reasonable price sell out, and then you're left with a handful with high (sometimes crazily high) prices. This can just happen naturally when some seller legitimately had a higher asking price, or somewhat more calculatedly when someone is trying to cash in on the reaming stock of a popular product. And sometimes I think it is shady vendors just trying to catch unobservant buyers with outrageous prices because there's no penalty for trying — buyer beware and all that.